# SELECT least value between two columns with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-null

Hello I am trying to select the smallest value between 3 columns with MySQL.

The issue I am facing is that in a column I might have `NULL` value. How can I get the least value that is not `NULL`?

Running `select least(1, 3, NULL)` will return `NULL` but I would like to have `1` as an answer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the types of the columns? Can they be negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `least()` handles `null`s is [a documented behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

> If any argument is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. No comparison is needed.

That might seem annoying, but propagating the `null` value to the resultset is how your database signals you that one of your values is undefined; this is consistent with the behavior of other operations that involve `null` (string concatenation, arithmetic operations, ...).

If only the third column may be `null`, and none of the other two, you could do:

```
least(col1, col2, coalesce(col3, col1))
```